# Understanding htaccess and how rules affect sub-directories

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My understanding was that a local .htaccess file (within the current directory) would override a .htaccess in a parent directory?

This does not seem to be the case and therefore I am hoping to seek a better understanding of the process and how it cascades.

I have a website in `/public_html` with a .htaccess

```
# BEGIN Domain Redirects
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then, I created a sub-directory at `/public_html/testing.example.com` and within there I implemented it's own `.htaccess` as follows:

```
# BEGIN Domain Redirects
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !testing.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://testing.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

My expectation is that when I access http://testing.example.com the domain will always remain http://testing.example.com because `/public_html/testing.example.com/.htaccess` would be the master directives file?

And this sort of works... Until I try to install WordPress... When I get to step 3 and click "Run the Install", the URL changes to http://www.example.com/testing.example.com/ and it throws an error.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/install.php on this
>   server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

To get around this now, I have to rename `/public_html/.htaccess` temporarily while I run an install on the sub-directory and then change it back after completion.

Is this normal behaviour? Am I wrong in assuming that the sub-directory `/public_html/testing.example.com/.htaccess` should be the master when accessing http://testing.example.com/?

Comment: I think I just answered my own question... I notice in the parent .htaccess that there is a directive:  <files install.php>
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
  </IfModule>
 </files>